# Stop a loop process in shell scripting after some time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bamboo

I have a script that looks like this, this script is checking whether my pods is in Running state or Not by redefining x on every loop.

```
x=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=${bamboo.shortPlanName} -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')

until [ "$x" == "Running" ];
do
   sleep 5
   x=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=${bamboo.shortPlanName} -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')
   echo $x
done
```

But, I want to modify my current script to also support timeout, I mean after 60 second of looping, then it should be stop, or after 12 times of looping, then it should be stop. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bash` provides a special variable `SECONDS` that can be used as a rough timer.

```
SECONDS=0
while (( SECONDS < 60)); do
    x=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=${bamboo.shortPlanName} -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')
    if [[ $x == Running ]]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

The expansion of `SECONDS` gives you not the assigned value, but the difference between the numbers of seconds *since* the assignment and the assigned value. The effect is like a variable whose value is incremented by 1 each second.

Comment: Wow, that's the first time that I hear about `SECONDS` despite the fact that it is an old functionality that works on bash 3.2

Comment: When I first learned about it, I only noticed the "seconds since shell startup" aspect; it was a few years before I realized you could set it to an arbitrary value and having the "counting" continue from there.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the answer, is it possible to add another condition, when 60 seconds is over, then the script will send a command "exit 1" ?

Comment: After the loop, `[[ $x == Running ]] || exit 1`. Either the loop exits because `x` is `Running`, or the loop exits because `SECONDS >= 60`.

Answer (score 1):

For timeout after 60 seconds try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readonly kOC_SLEEP_SECS=5
readonly kOC_TIMEOUT_SECS=60

initial_secs=$SECONDS
while
    status=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=bamboo.shortPlanName       \
                -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')
    printf '%s\n' "$status"
    [[ $status != Running ]]
do
    if (( (SECONDS - initial_secs) >= kOC_TIMEOUT_SECS )); then
        echo 'ERROR: Timed out' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    sleep -- "$kOC_SLEEP_SECS"
done
```

- I replaced `app=${bamboo.shortPlanName}` with `app=bamboo.shortPlanName` because the old code was causing Bash errors.  You'll need to fix it properly.
- See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf` for printing the status.
- The code treats a timeout as an error, and exits with bad status.  You might want to do something different.
- The actual timeout period will be somewhere between 60 and 65 (or maybe a little more) seconds.  You'll need to do something different if you need a more accurate timeout.

For a timeout after 12 iterations try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean variation on the code above:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readonly kOC_SLEEP_SECS=5
readonly kOC_MAX_ITERS=12

oc_iters=0
while
    status=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=bamboo.shortPlanName           \
                -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')
    printf '%s\n' "$status"
    [[ $status != Running ]]
do
   if (( ++oc_iters >= kOC_MAX_ITERS )); then
       echo 'ERROR: Timed out' >&2
       exit 1
    fi
   sleep -- "$kOC_SLEEP_SECS"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `trap` is the easiest way to have an accurate timeout.

Prototype:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

HALT=0
TIMEOUT=4

# Trap for SIGALRM
stop_loop() {
    HALT=1
}

# Set trap
trap stop_loop SIGALRM

# The timeout goes after $TIMEOUT seconds.
{ sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -SIGALRM $$ & }

# Main loop
until false || [[ $HALT -eq 1 ]]; do 
    sleep 1
    echo 'loop'
done

echo 'out of loop'
exit 0
```

In your case, this looks a something like:

```sh
HALT=0
TIMEOUT=4

stop_loop() {
    HALT=1
}

trap stop_loop SIGALRM

x=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=${bamboo.shortPlanName} \
    -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')

{ sleep $TIMEOUT && kill -SIGALRM $$ & }

until [ "$x" == "Running" ] || [[ $HALT -eq 1 ]];
do
   sleep 5
   x=$(/opt/oc get pods --selector app=${bamboo.shortPlanName} \
        -o jsonpath='{range .items[]}{.status.phase}{"\n"}{end}')
   echo $x
done
exit 0
```